# How to create Independent Html.PartialView in Style Files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Controller and Action

```
public class RentCarController : Controller
{
 public ActionResult Cars()
    {
        return PartialView("Cars");
    }
}
```

Cars.cshtml:

```
<script src="/plugins/bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>

<link href="/eliteadmin-material/bootstrap3/dist/css/bootstrap3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Date picker plugins css -->
<link href="/plugins/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

 <div class="example">
   <h5 class="box-title m-t-30">Date Range Pick</h5>
   <input class="form-control input-daterange-datepicker" type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015" />
 </div>
```

Layout:

```
<head>
  <link href="/eliteadmin-material/bootstrap4/dist/css/bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 4 Mixed =( Its not work

Question : I used layout bootstrap 4 . Can I using bootstrap 3 in PartialView("Cars");

Edit:It's Visual Studio have error wonder ? =(

Thanks for answers

Comment: Sorry! Not following your question. Can you update the question to be a bit more detailed ?

Comment: partial view is independent of Layouts .partial views are meant of for that purpose.

Comment: Please update your question with more details

Comment: Different Style Files not support ?